# If $\delta \colon R[x_1, \dotsc, x_r] \to M$ is an $R$-derivation, then $\delta P = \sum_{i = 1}^r \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i} dx_i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, commutative-algebra, modules, differential-algebra

Let $\phi \colon R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism and $M$ an $S$-module. An $R$-derivation $\delta \colon S \rightarrow M$ is a $R$-module homomorphism such that:

1. $\phi(R) \subset \ker(\delta)$,
2. (Leibniz’ rule:) $\delta(s s') = s \delta s' + s' \delta s$ for all $s, s' \in S$.

Then, according to the exercises on my lecture notes, if $\delta \colon R[x_1, \dotsc, x_r] \rightarrow M$ is an $R$-derivation, then $\delta P = \sum_{i = 1}^r \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i} dx_i$. I’m not totally sure what they mean by $dx_i$ here, since I think they don’t have defined the operator $d$ as far as I know. I guess it should be just the same as $\delta x_i$?

I’d like to prove this. I thought of doing it by induction: for the case $r = 1$, it is fairly easy to see using the above properties that $\delta P = \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \delta x$. Then, if we write a multivariable polynomial as $\sum_{j = 0}^k a_j x^j_{n + 1}$, where $a_j \in R[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$, we may assume that the result holds for $n$ and try to prove it for $n + 1$:
$$
  \delta P
  = \delta\Biggl( \sum_{j = 0}^k a_j x^j_{n+1} \Biggr)
  = \sum_{j = 0}^k \Bigl( a_j \delta(x_{n+1}^j) + \delta(a_j) x_{n+1}^j \Bigr)
$$
… where we may use that $\delta(x_{n+1}^j) = j x_{n+1}^{j-1} \delta(x_{n+1})$ and that $\delta(a_j) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial{a_j}}{\partial{x_i}}dx_i$ (because of the induction hypothesis), but I don’t really know where to go from there.

I guess it’s a matter of manipulating expressions with polynomials in several variables, but I’m also not entirely sure what the exercise expects me to prove (as I don’t know what “$dx_i$” is).

Comment: it should propably be $\delta(x_i)$ instead of $dx_i$. If $\delta$ is such a derivation and if $f:=x_i^n$ it follows $\delta(f)=\delta(x_i^n)=nx_i^{n-1}\delta(x_i):=\partial_{x_i}(f)\delta(x_i)$.

Comment: When you say "for $r = 1$, it is fairly easy," have you actually written that part out?

Comment: @TrevorGunn Yes I have, but it actually seemed to me kind of tautological that $\delta P=\delta(\sum a_j x^j)=\sum a_j \delta(x^j) = \sum j a_j x^{j-1} \delta(x)$ is the same as $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \delta x$… provided $dx=\delta x$, of course. I find this whole exercise a bit confusing…

Comment: By induction you may prove that $\delta(f(x_1,..,x_n))=\sum_i \partial_{x_i}(f)\delta(x_i)$. There is the "module of Kahler differentials" $\Omega^1_{S/R}=S\{dx_1,..,dx_n\}$ when $S:=R[x_i]$, and an isomorphism $Der_R(S,M) \cong Hom_S(\Omega^1_{S/R}, M)$.

Comment: I think if you spend more time showing that $\delta(x^n) = nx^{n-1} \delta(x)$, this exercise will make more sense. Remember that the rule you're working with is the Leibnitz rule, so you have to do this inductively: $\delta(x \cdot x^n) = x \delta(x^n) + \delta(x) x^n$. And then if you have two variables, how can you compute $\delta(x^m y^n)$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn Yes, I had already proved that $\delta(x^n)=nx^{n-1}\delta(x)$ by induction, forgot to mention it. I guess $\delta(x^m y^n)=\delta(x^m)y^n+x^m \delta(y^n)$?

Comment: @hm2020 Thank you, I will look into that, but what do you mean exactly by the notation $S\{dx_1, \ldots, dx_n\}$?

Comment: @dahemar - this mean the "direct sum" $S$-module on the elements $dx_1,..,dx_n$: $\Omega^1_{S/R}\cong \oplus_i Sdx_i$. You find the construction of the "module of Kahler differentials" in Matsumuras book on commutative ring theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$ be a commutative ring, let $A$ be a commutative $$-algebra and let $M$ be an $A$-module.
We abbreviate “$$-derivation” as derivation”.

### Some general observations.

1. For any two derivations $δ, δ' \colon A \to M$ their equalizer $\{ a ∈ A \mid δ(a) = δ'(a) \}$ is a $$-subalgebra of $A$.
   Consequently, any derivation from $A$ to $M$ is uniquely determined by its action on a $$-algebra generating set of $A$.
2. Let us denote by $\mathrm{Der}_(A, M)$ the subspace of $\mathrm{Hom}_(A, M)$ consisting of derivations.
   The $$-module $\mathrm{Hom}_(A, M)$ is actually an $A$-module via $(a f)(a') ≔ a f(a')$, and $\mathrm{Der}_(A, M)$ is an $A$-submodule of $\mathrm{Hom}_(A, M)$.
   More explicitly, $A$-linear combination of derivations are again derivations.
3. If $N$ in another $A$-module and $f \colon M \to N$ is a homomorphism of $A$-modules, then for every derivation $δ \colon A \to M$ the composite $f ∘ δ \colon A \to N$ is again a derivation.

Let now $A = [x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$.
Every $$-derivation $A \to M$ is uniquely determined by the values $δ(x_1), \dotsc, δ(x_n)$ thanks to observation (1).

### The special case $M = A$.

Let us consider the special case $M = A$ for a moment.
The partial derivative maps $∂_i ≔ ∂ / ∂ x_i \colon A \to A$ are derivations with
$$
  ∂_i( x_j ) = δ_{ij}
$$
for all $i, j = 1, \dotsc, n$.
It follows from these equations that for every choice of coefficients $a_1, \dotsc, a_n ∈ A$ the derivation $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i ∂_i$ satisfies
$$
  \biggl( \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i ∂_i \biggr)( x_j )
  = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i ∂_i( x_j )
  = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i δ_{ij}
  = a_j
$$
for every $j = 1, \dotsc, n$.
Since every derivation $δ \colon A \to A$ is uniquely determined by its values $δ(x_1), \dotsc, δ(x_n)$, it further follows that every element of $\mathrm{Der}_(A, A)$ is a unique $A$-linear combination of $∂_1, \dotsc, ∂_n$.
In other words, $\mathrm{Der}_(A, A)$ is free as an $A$-module with basis $∂_1, \dotsc, ∂_n$.

As formulas, every derivation $δ \colon A \to A$ is given by $δ = \sum_{i = 1}^n δ(x_i) ∂_i$, or more explicitly by
$$
  δ(p) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{∂ p}{∂ x_i} δ(x_i)
$$
for every polynomial $p ∈ A$.

### The general case.

Let now $M$ be an arbitrary $A$-module.
Every element $m$ of $M$ corresponds to a homomorphism of $A$-modules
$$
  f_m \colon A \longrightarrow M \,, \quad a \longmapsto am \,.
$$
According to observation (3) we can use the homomorphism $f_m$ to push forward derivations $δ \colon A \to A$ to derivations $f_m ∘ δ \colon A \to M$.
We denote the derivation $f_m ∘ δ$ by $δ m$, so that
$$
  (δ m)(a) = δ(a) m \,.
$$
We find in particular that
$$
  (∂_i m)(x_j) = ∂_i(x_j) m = δ_{ij} m \,.
$$
Since every derivation $δ \colon A \to M$ is uniquely determined by its values $δ(x_1), \dotsc, δ(x_n)$, we find that every such derivation $δ$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination
$$
  δ = \sum_{i = 1}^n ∂_i m_i
$$
with $m_1, \dotsc, m_n ∈ M$.
More explicitly, the “coefficients” $m_i$ are given by $m_i = δ(x_i)$.
This entails the following:

- Every derivation $δ \colon A \to M$ is of the form $δ = \sum_{i = 1}^n ∂_i δ(x_i)$, or more explicitly
  $$
    δ(p) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{∂ p}{∂ x_i} δ(x_i)
  $$
  for every polynomial $p$.
- The isomorphism of $A$-modules $\mathrm{Der}_(A, A) ≅ A^{⊕ n}$ generalizes to an isomorphism of $A$-modules $\mathrm{Der}_(A, M) ≅ M^{⊕ n}$.